# Phantomjs cannot open a page that browser opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I have a Phantomjs script that tries to open a url. phantomjs returns this error:

```
Unable to load resource (request ID:undefinedURL:http://foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27)
Error code: 203. Description: Error downloading http://foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27 - server replied: Not Found
```

But when I open the url `http://foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27` with chrome browser, there's no problem and the page is loaded correctly!

This is the script:

```
// Read the Phantom webpage '#intro' element text using jQuery and "includeJs"

"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

if (system.args.length != 2) {
    console.log("please pass 2 argument")
}
var company_id = system.args[1]
console.log("c", company_id)

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log("message", msg);
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (request ID:' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);

};

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    console.log("error", msg)
}

var nav_value;

page.open("http://foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27", 'post', 'username=navid&password=test', function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                nav_value = parseInt($("#value").text());
            });
            phantom.exit(0);
        });
    } else {
      phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Something odd happens. When I run this code with phantomjs on windows on another machine it works. But on Ubuntu it returns the error!

The url that phantomjs is trying to open is on the same server. (Ubuntu)

What is the problem?

Comment: `But when I open the url with chrome` - do you make a GET request with Chrome? Note that you make a POST request with PhantomJS.

Comment: yes I make a GET request. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Depending on the site it could make. Try requesting the same page with GET request in PhantomJS now for the sake of experiment. If the page would still be not found... could there be a typo in the script? Pity you can't show the site URL, I have a couple of other theories as to why this error could be.

Comment: I used it with GET. Still not working. It works on windows on another machine but not in linux. it's weird!

Comment: Is http://foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27 a correct url? Is it your local server?

Comment: No I changed the url. I cannot paste the actual url.

Comment: Must be a typo or some network restrictions. Anyway without actual url we cant help.

Comment: Also could be that ubuntu server IP is banned from accessing that site.

Comment: @Navid777, please try to open `foo.bar/tree/nav_value/27` via `curl` or `wget` from the same Ubuntu server as the site. Are there errors?

Comment: Your underscore in the path is causing all the trouble. If possible replace them with hyphen. To be sure try to get contents of file which does not have underscore.

Comment: Can you use Postman in Chrome to make the request? Does a POST on this URL work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help, but I have some ideas that helped me figure out problems with PhantomJS in the past.

First, as you say it works on another machine, you may want to test [other versions of PhantomJS](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads), by downloading the executable and specifying the path on your Python script. Version 1.9.8 helped me with bypassing some security restrictions in the past (I also left some settings in case it may interest).

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
    executable_path='/path/to/the/downloaded/phantomjs19',
    # you can specify args, such as:
    service_args=[
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', 
        '--ssl-protocol=any', 
        '--web-security=false',
    ],
    # and also other capabilities:
    desired_capabilities={
        'phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout': '5000',
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent': (
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
        ),
    },
)
```

You may also try to see if upgrading Selenium helps.

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

Another idea that might help to understand what is happening is to try to print a screenshot and log the page source before the error happens. You can do it like:

```
# Set the window size to something appropriate for your tests.
driver.set_window_size(900, 800)
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')

# Check if the page source matches your expectations.
with open('temp.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Please, let me know if this helps!